# Sending out a daily survey via redcap and Twilio

Tags: twilio, redcap

We are hoping to use Redcap + Twilio to conduct a "daily diary" (ecological momentary assessment or EMA) study with N=150 people. The study will involve a 7-week period in which participants will be asked to complete a brief survey each morning, each evening, and once per week. The morning surveys will be the same each time, as will be the evening surveys and weekly surveys.

Is there a way to schedule the same survey to be sent out daily (and weekly) without using the “events” feature?

Comment: Can you use a [repeat instrument](https://www.ctsi.ufl.edu/wordpress/files/2017/06/Repeating-Instruments-and-Events-1.pdf) for this?

Comment: We did look into that. However, we need the survey to be sent out at 8 AM and scheduling a specific time to be sent did not look like an option with repeat instrument.

Comment: Ah, ok, how about the [calendar application](https://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=irsa)? What is the "events" feature and why do you not want to use it if it solves your problem?

Comment: The calendar application is only to keep track of patient's schedules. Unfortunately, nothing can be sent out from it. We have had success using the events feature, but it requires us setting up 49 different events for the morning survey to be sent out each day, 49 events for the evening survey to be sent out each day, and 7 events for each weekly survey to be sent out. As we recruit a new group of patients each month, we have to set up these 100+ events every time. We were hoping to not have to do this if there was a better way.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to script that, so that it's a less manual process. I'm afraid I don't really know the REDCap system, just trying to help out with Twilio stuff.

Comment: Consider asking your institution's REDCap admin to post this question on the "REDCap Community website".

Answer (score 1):

We did something similar where we set up a repeated instrument and an Alert/Notification. The alert notification was set to first be sent on the required date/time, and then every 24 hours (or every 1 day) for the next x (42 in our case) days.

[image]

[image]

The text in the alert/notification provided a link to the participants survey queue with the repeating instrument and gave the date that the last repeated survey was completed. This is not ideal as the survey queue gives each instance of the repeated instrument the same name, and cannot include the date in the title.